# Java: Encryption not working in command line

Tags: java, encryption

I'm using the following to code to encrypt a value:

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class crypto {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        String s1 = args[1];
        String ivkey = "1234567891234567891235478912345";
        byte[] ivraw = ivkey.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(ivraw, "AES");

        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("ENCRYPT")) {
            try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(s1.getBytes());
                System.out.println(new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted)));
                System.out.println(s1);

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException
                    | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                    | BadPaddingException e) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(s1.getBytes());
                System.out.println(new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted)));

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException
                    | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                    | BadPaddingException e) {
            }

        }
        return;
    };
}
```

However, whenever I compile it and then run the code, I receive no errors and it just spits back to me the value of `s1` and not its encrypted value. I'm not entirely sure where I'm going wrong here, I receive no errors during compilation or during runtime.

I've placed in markers to track my progress through the app and it seems to be hitting all the key points. My concern is the `Base64` not working, since I do have to compile with `javac -classpath "/path/to/commons.jar" crypto.java` but I can't tell if it is or it is not.

Your assistance is appreciated

Comment: You ignore possible exceptions. At least print the stacktrace in the catch clauses.

Comment: Please replace the empty exception handling with `throw new RuntimeException(e)` and see what happens.

Comment: Note that 0 is an important number when counting. You're counting base 9 instead of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key is too small, it's 31 bytes. Make it 16 bytes and you would have AES-128. A key should never be a string, it should be indistinguishable from random (as bytes or bits). The size of the IV is fixed for AES, it should be 16 bytes (or `cipher.getBlockSize()`), not less, but certainly not more either.

Make sure you understand a bit about applied cryptography. You are currently using ECB mode encryption, which is unsafe for text (and most other uses of a block cipher, really). Keys should not be strings, the IV should be randomized. Just using `"AES"` does not make your code cryptographically safe.

Don't shove exceptions under the table, and try and use an IDE with debugger.

Comment: I should have noted, I'm using a 32 byte key I just changed it for the sake of posting online. :\ Apologies for that.

Comment: Well, after changing the key size the base64 is printed when I run it on my machine. Note that for ECB, the output is empty if `s1` is empty. But you should always create a 16 byte IV.